# Redis Scan - Bash remove prefix

Tags: bash, redis, pattern-matching

If I have a response like this from Redis Scan:

```
response=12345
abc1
abc2
```

How can I get the keys abc1 & abc2?
Currently using something like this but keys is always empty:

```
keys=${response##[0-9]*[0-9 ]}
```

I have another key just abc and redis return from scan will give:

```
response=12345
abc
```

Using the same code it keys will output

```
key=
abc
```

In the case of abc1 & abc2
desired output is:

```
key=
abc1
abc2
```

I just want the initial numbers which are the iterated figure returned from redis for you to scan the next iteration, I just want these removed and keep the keys even if keys have numbers in them.
If you just run redis on command line is should output something like this:

```
1) 12345
2) 
  1)abc1
  2)abc2
```

Comment: `response` is a shell variable (or) part of the command output?

Comment: Can you show us an actual command output and what information you want to get out of it? And what is your `bash` version, show is the output of `bash --version`?

Comment: Thanks for the response, bash version is version 4.3.11 and the output is the last section I showed there. The command is: `redis-cli -h $1 SCAN $cursor MATCH $2 COUNT $3` Where $1 is the redis endpoint, $2 is the pattern to match and $3 is the number which SCAN should iterate.
Response is the shell variable I put the command output into.